# Why does my breakpoint never get hit, when using AutoMock.GetLoose()?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, moq

Consider the following simple test:

```
[Fact]
public void Should_Test_Something()
{
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {
        using (var workflow = mock.Create<IWorkflow>())
        {
            var result = workflow.DoSomething();
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

When setting a breakpoint inside of `DoSomething()` Visual Studio will never break upon it. Why is that? I can step through the test without any issues.

```
public interface IWorkflow
{
    bool DoSomething();
}

public class Workflow : IWorkflow
{
    public Workflow( // Some long list of dependencies...)

    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        // I do something, a breakpoint set here does never get hit
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. Then how can I test my method `DoSomething()` in an isolated way, without having to supply all the dependencies?

Comment: You mock the dependencies and create an instance of the concrete class under test.

Comment: You will need to mock all the dependencies and initialize the actual class with those dependencies.

Comment: I thought that was the whole point of using `AutoMock.GetLoose()`... that it automagically takes care of the dependencies.

Comment: @Nkosi , it sounds like mocking will require you to follow all the steps that calling the actual class would. Why use mock rather than the class itself? Unless I'm missing something

Comment: Yes but you asked for the interface and not the class

Comment: It does take care of the dependencies, but you have to create an instance *of the concrete class*, not the interface. Should be `using (var workflow = mock.Create<Workflow>())`

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard, thanks, that did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When setting a breakpoint inside of DoSomething() Visual Studio will never break upon it. Why is that? I can step through the test without any issues.

Because the interface is being mock and used. not the actual class implementation.

That is the whole point of mocking the interface to begin with. So that the actual class is not used. But rather the mock of the interface.

> how can I test my method DoSomething() in an isolated way, without having to supply all the dependencies?

You will need to mock all the dependencies and initialize the actual class with those dependencies.

```
[Fact]
public void Should_Test_Something() {
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()) {
        //Arrange
        IWorkflow workflow = mock.Create<Workflow>(); //<-- note asking for actual class

        //Act
        var result = workflow.DoSomething();

        //Assert
        // ...assert expected behavior            
    }
}
```

Provided all the dependencies can be created with out undesirable behavior the auto mock with create mocks of the dependencies and pass that to the class.